# Button title does not show up

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uibutton

I got a UIButton with a background-image and a title. Wenn it's pressed (and holding), I should change it's background-image (WHICH DOES WORK), but keep it's title. But when I press the button, the title disappears and even when released, it also doesnt shop up again.

```
    @IBAction func holdingTheButton(_ sender: Any) {

            numberButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonIn.png"), for: .normal)
            numberButton.setTitle("Refuel", for: .normal)
}
```

This is a part of my holdingTheButton function (already declared/ initialized the button etc.), where I try to keep the title "Refuel". Btw: Changing to "for: .highlighted" or "for: .selected" doesnt change anything.

[Screenshot of my Buttons configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaSkZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you press the UIButton it state is changed to highlighted when it's clicked. UIButton has different states such as selected, normal, highlighted and more.

If you would like the image and the title to stay the same you have got to call again "setTitle" and "setImage" for state "highlighted"

In your "ViewDidLoad" do the following:

```
  numberButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonIn.png"), for: .normal)
  numberButton.setTitle("Refuel", for: .normal)
        numberButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonIn.png"), for: .highlighted)
  numberButton.setTitle("Refuel", for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the Buttons title is still not showing up

Comment: try doing the same for the selected state ".selected", and do it in the "viewDidLoad" func not in the "holdingTheButton" func

Comment: Ohhh I got it. I was using .setImage instead of .setBackgroundImage